# How to navigate to page when GridViewItem is clicked?

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a GridView which contains 2 items defined as follow :

```
<GridView Name="Grd1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="GridViewItem_Click">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridViewItem  Name ="GrdI1">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100" Source="Image1.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Some sutff"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem Name="GrdI2" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100" Source="Image2.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some stuff"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridViewItem>
    </GridView>
```

How can i handle the event on code behind to navigate to page 1 when the item GrdI1 is clicked and page 2 when the item GrdI2 is clicked ?

Comment: Can you provide whole xaml code? So I could paste it and see whether I'm able to help you

Comment: This is already the entire xaml code for the gridview. Just paste it to a modern app sample in visual studio and it will works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to handle click events in GridView you must set GridView's IsItemClickEnabled property to True and SelectionMode to None.

Set a new event handler for ItemClick event and in ItemClickEventArgs parameter (e by default) you can catch the clicked event. (e.ClickedItem)

This will give you what Item you clicked in GridView and you can use Frame.Navigate method to navigate your pages.

Modify your xaml code like this

```
<GridView Name="Grd1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="GridViewItem_Click">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridViewItem  Name ="GrdI1">
            <StackPanel Tag="Grid1">
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100" Source="Image1.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Some sutff"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridViewItem>
        <GridViewItem Name="GrdI2" >
            <StackPanel Tag="Grid2">
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Width="100" Source="Image2.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Some stuff"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </GridViewItem>
    </GridView>
```

And your event handler must be like this

```
private void Grd1_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedItem = ((StackPanel)e.ClickedItem);
        if (clickedItem.Tag != null)
            if (clickedItem.Tag.ToString() == "Grid1")
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
            else
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }
```

Comment: In fact i want to get the name of the clicked GridViewItem but i don't know how to do that because my e.ClickedItem hasn't such property ...

Comment: You can bind your GridViewItem's name to Stackpanel's Tag property and catch in the event.

Comment: Thank you but could you give a sample code ? It will be better to understand.

Comment: Just modified my answer above.